# «В море корабли расходятся в тумане, маяком маня»

Tags: грамотная-речь, деепричастный-оборот, лексическая-сочетаемость

Вот кусочек из [известной песни](http://slushat-tekst-pesni.ru/valeriya/my-razoshlis-kak-v-more-korabli) Валерии:

> *Мы разошлись, как в море корабли
>
> Расходятся в тумане, **маяком маня.***
> Не надо больше мне такой любви.
> Не обижай меня! Не обижай меня!

Я считаю, что предложение построено неверно — корабли не могут никого и ничего манить маяком.
Разоспорились на работе вдрызг: популярная песня не может быть неправильной!
Помогите, пожалуйста, грамотно растолковать коллегам неточность.
Как может выглядеть правильное предложение? (Или это я ошибаюсь?)

[«Не обижай меня»](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X68fFdT1PSc)
[Маяк](https://supersasha.ru/posts/12448/)

Comment: Видео по ссылке не работает. Хотел заменить на ссылку на ютьюб, но не стал, поскольку понял, что у вас там ещё текст был.

Comment: Для рифмы и исправления смысла подошло бы "рындами звоня/звеня" (рында - корабельный сигнальный колокол), но это звучало бы слишком специфично для стихотворного текста.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Хорошо, Артем, что Вы не стали больше ничего менять. Мне ведь был нужен текст, а не изображение или звук.

Comment: По Вашей ссылке текст показывается, но видеоклип (для изменения текста нужно послушать, как он был вписан в мелодию) не запускается (возможно, блокировка по России в коммерческих интересах). Есть на ютюбе:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X68fFdT1PSc
Безобидный, без морских терминов, вариант замены проблемной строки (в конце предыдущей строки - запятая, заканчивающая ссылку на корабли): "В тумане настроений рокового дня".

Comment: Премного благодарна Вам, *Alex_ander*! Использовала Вашу ссылку в своем вопросе (надеюсь, Вы не против).

Answer (score 3):

> корабли не могут никого и ничего манить маяком.

Не совсем так. Если заменить поэтическое "манить" на близкое по значению "призывать", то могут. Маяк-то это ж не только на берегу, но и радиомяак на судне, особенно воздушном. Или даже обычный светозвуковой "подвижный" маяк на лоцманской станции. Подобное, правда, имеет смысл разве что в случае, когда судно терпит бедствие и призывает помощь. Или идет в порт, а подвижный маяк его туда "манит". Ну или в космосе корабль идет на стыковку.

Другое дело, что в контексте сие - абсолютная чушь. Когда суда "расходятся бортами", то им не манить надо друг друга, а стараться держаться подальше. Особенно в тумане.
Впрочем, давно известно, что искать смысла в текстовках современной попсы - дело весьма неблагодарное.
(+)
Задался целью найти первоисточник самого выражения "разошлись как в море корабли" (в версии Остапа Бендера) или "как ночью корабли" от автора слов и музыки романса "Корабли" Бориса Прозоровского.

Нашел, к сожалению, только два четверостишья.
Одно из которых действительно имеет эту строчку.

*Мы никогда друг друга не любили

В своих сердцах привета не носили,

Случайных встреч и взоров не ценили,

И разошлись, как ночью корабли.*

*Но, разойдясь, сквозь сумраки ночные

Мы с трепетом в сердцах своих прочли,

Что наши души близкие, родные,

Что полюбить друг друга мы могли…*
http://a-pesni.org/romans/prozorovsky/korabli.php
Не знаю, весь ли это романс, но "почувствуйте разницу".

(++)

Я понял! Капитаны "Нахимова" "Петра Васева" были поэтами!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и за стихи Б. Прозоровского. Вот тут еще есть информация о романсе: https://lera-komor.livejournal.com/1808559.html

Answer (score 2):

Маяк – **многозначное понятие.**

МАЯК,  1. Высокое сооружение башенного типа, оборудованное сильным источником света, 2. Устройство, оборудованное звуковой, световой или радиотехнической сигнализацией для навигационного ориентирования судов, самолетов и т.п. Маяки взлетной полосы аэродрома. Установить звуковой маяк.

Кроме того,  это может быть образным сравнением:  ***Манит  как маяк*** (маяком).

**Анализ текста**

Я не рассматриваю общую композицию, ничего не говорю об уровне художественного исполнения. Речь идет только о конкретном предложении: *Мы разошлись, как в море корабли Расходятся в тумане, **маяком маня**.*

**Предложение построено  корректно,** нет стилистических или грамматических погрешностей (по крайней мере, я их не вижу).

Comment: Расходящиеся корабли, будь в их огнях что-то вроде маяка (допустим, это _метафора_ стихотворца-песенника), должны не "манить" друг дружку, а наоборот, предупреждать движение к сближению (условно говоря, отпугивать). Третьей стороны, которой огни расходящихся в море короблей показались бы привлекательными, попросту нет - и это вторая составляющая "когнитивной рениксы",

Comment: Да, не поэт (в смысле сентиментального сочинительства), зато охотливый критик плохих поэтов, к которым отношу большинство профессиональных песенников с их "виньетками ложных сутей" :) У меня неплохая практика стихотворных переводов (между русским и английским в двух направлениях) - сужу с этих позиций.

Comment: Артем, сотрите, пожалуйста, комментарий, как обещали.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за особое видение, Sharon.

Comment: Спасибо, Римма!

Comment: Простите, не в тему, но хочу поделиться своей находкой: ударением *д**о**быча* у Крылова. Оказывается, этим шахтёры оправдывали своё профессиональное жаргонное ударение: https://rg.ru/2014/05/29/dobicha.html!

Answer (score 1):

Это был **комментарий**, посвященный  теме критической оценке поэзии (он удален). Я говорила о том, насколько объективна может быть критика. В частности, я вспомнила критика Луганского, погубившего Мастера (у которого, как считают, есть реальный прототип). Также я говорила о личном восприятии поэзии, о том, насколько часто истинные шедевры встречаются даже в творчестве великих поэтов. И еще  том, что в поэзии главное – это образ, что она в первую очередь обращена к чувствам слушателей. Чувствительное сердце раньше (во времена Пушкина) считалось достоинством, а теперь у нас в ходу выражение "сентиментальные сопли".

Далее цитирую: *"Извините, конечно, но это не образ, это поток сознания, интересный разве что психиатру".*

Отвечаю: Что касается **потока сознания**, то вообще-то это художественный прием и даже целое литературное направление. Там свои законы в организации художественного материала.  **Но в любом случае спасибо Вам за направление к психиатру.**

Comment: извините, конечно, но это не образ, это поток сознания, интересный разве что психиатру.

Answer (score 1):

Второй ответ

Заинтересованные пользователи Интернета  давно уже обсуждают  известную фразу,  выражая, как правило,  решительное неприятие этого  низкопробного  художественного образа.

С другой стороны, **тема маяка в поэзии отнюдь не нова**, «охранительный свет маяков» с чем только не сравнивался.  Вот и великие поэты не обошли его своим вниманием: *«Любовь — над бурей поднятый маяк, не меркнущий во мраке и тумане, Любовь — звезда, которою моряк определяет место в океане»* (Вильям Шекспир). «*Мой милый маг, моя Мария, Мечтам мерцающий маяк*» (В. Брюсов).

Это великие, а что уж там говорит о поэтах обычных, сентиментальность которых иногда просто зашкаливает, например: "Ты как маяк в таинственной ночи – то загоришься, то опять погаснешь". И звукописное сочетание  «**манит меня маяк**»  тоже не сейчас придумали, например: «*Как манит ночью корабли маяк*…»

Так почему же **никто не ругает Шекспира за интерес к маякам**, а вот песней недовольны все. Причем критикуют одно-единственное предложение, считая, что никак расходящиеся в море корабли маяками манить друг друга не могут.

Однако если приглядеться к этой фразе, то можно увидеть там **разную грамматику:**

(1) *Мы разошлись, как в море корабли Расходятся в тумане, маяком маня*. **Маня (чем?) маяком.** Да, не очень складно.

(2) *Мы разошлись, как в море корабли Расходятся в тумане, маяком маня*.  Маня маяком, маня как маяк. А это **инверсия обычного и вполне заурядного сравнения**. Светящийся в тумане корабль похож на маяк, вот  и манит огнями, как маяк. **Реальный же маяк**, будто бы установленный на корабле,  здесь вообще необязателен.

Что же касается художественного образа, то он   достаточно интересен, и понимать его можно так. Когда люди расходятся, когда утрачивается  былая душевная близость, что-то еще некоторое время притягивает их друг к другу. И вот это что-то напоминает **свет постепенно удаляющегося корабля.**