# Еще о метафоре "как в море корабли"

Tags: метафора

По итогам своего размышления над упоминаемой в вопросе [«В море корабли расходятся в тумане, маяком маня»](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462254) метафорой "как в море корабли" появился вопрос. Оговорюсь, что слово "метафора" употребляю от некоторой безысходности, предложения по замене термина будут приняты благожелательно.

Итак. Метафора сия существует в трех вариантах:
~1 ***Разошлись(,) как в море корабли*** - в современных реалиях основной (озвученный впервые, вероятно, Остапом Бендером).
~2 ***Разошлись(,) как ночью корабли*** - авторский, Бориса Прозоровского http://a-pesni.org/romans/prozorovsky/korabli.php .
~3 ***Разошлись(,) как в тумане корабли*** - окказиональный, неизвестного происхождения.

Вопрос: что стоит за каждым вариантом, какие ассоциации возникают, какой из вариантов более емок и поэтичен? *Сомнительной запятой прошу здесь не уделять излишне много внимания, её необходимомть определяется оценкой уровня фразеологичности каждого из вариантов, здесь выносим за скобки.*

Понимаю, ответ всегда чуточку субъективен, но, думаю, не настолько, чтобы выходил за пределы "формата". Просто очень хочу понять, насколько я всё это правильно прочувствовал...

(+)----
*О романсе Прозоровского - например тут:*
https://lera-komor.livejournal.com/1808559.html

*Благодарю @РиммаМихайлова за эту ссылку.*

(++)-----
Я прошу учесть, что вариант "как в тумане" я не привязываю к словам песни. Во-первых, в песне есть и море, и туман, во-вторых, не о песне речь вообще.

Answer (score 1):

Я воспринимаю вариант "**как в море корабли**" как удобную своей краткостью и не отягощенную конкретными смыслами *присказку* (почему? - да потому: корабли расходятся, вот и мы тоже), как устоявшийся элемент фольклора (возможно даже, блатного).

Почему корабли расходятся? Корабли в море расходятся либо по причине различия курсов следования, либо во избежание столкновения - это настолько реальная опасность, что существуют пресловутые ППСС (Правила предупреждения столкновения судов). В варианте "**как в море корабли Расходятся в тумане**" видна попытка уйти от избитого выражения, при этом "**туман**" вроде как способствует стремлению кораблей разойтись подальше (повышенная опасность) - это добавление ничего не портит, поскольку объяснимо; с "маяком" - отдельная спорная история (по мне - смыслы оказались побиты рифмой). Вариант "**как ночью корабли**" из романса мне непонятен: корабли "расходятся" в любое время суток, независимо от причин, - видимо, это не более чем попытка уйти от навязчивой присказки.

Comment: Спасибо. Надеюсь, что будут еще ответы, потом дам свой.

Answer (score 0):

*Разошлись(,) как в море корабли* — самая из предложенных логичная и устойчивая форма, ставшая фразеологизмом. Она более предметно (нежели метафорически) рисует масштаб события — драмы или трагедии, — соотносимый с морским пространством. При этом представляется, — вовсе не на встречных курсах расхождение произошло, а некогда параллельным, общим.

Comment: OK. Спасибо.++++